# How to get the activation code for salesforce site

Tags: community

Im using devloper edition past two year, I forgot my password but if i click the forgotten password link and it moves new page, then type my username and its sends new link to my mail id , once i got the link and click the link its asking sceret question then i entered my secret answer and it goes to activation code page , but unfortunatley i was changed my mobile number , then how to get my activation code or  Any solution for login into my devloper edition , kindly plaese help me....

Thanks and Regards,
Ganesh

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to log a support ticket with salesforce to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks anup , but developer edition i thought no support ticket or tell me to rasie the ticket for devloper edition